# Update permission status after permission is allowed in delphi mobile app

Tags: android, ios, delphi, mobile, firemonkey

I am developing a Delphi mobile app on both Android and iOS platforms that requires to show notifications. When I first click on the button, it will request notification permission. However, after I click on the 'Allow' button on the dialog that prompts for permission, the notification doesn't show. I need to press the button again in order to show the notification.

Is there any way to let my application get the status immediately after I allow notification permission for the application?

Below is my prototype code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var notiCenter := TNotificationCenter.Create(nil);
  notiCenter.OnPermissionRequestResult := NotificationCenterPermissionRequestResult;
  
  if notiCenter.AuthorizationStatus <> TAuthorizationStatus.Authorized then
    notiCenter.RequestPermission;
  
  if FIsNotificationAllowed then begin
    var noti := notiCenter.CreateNotification;
    try
      noti.Name := 'Button Click';
      noti.Title := 'Button Click';
      noti.AlertBody := 'Button Click';
      notiCenter.PresentNotification(noti);
    finally
      noti.DisposeOf;
    end;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.NotificationCenterPermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject;
  const AIsGranted: Boolean);
begin
  if AIsGranted then FIsNotificationAllowed := true
  else FIsNotificationAllowed := false;
end;
```

Comment: You are attempting to check `FIsNotificationAllowed` before it may have been set. You could move the code that creates the notification into a separate routine, and call it if `AuthorizationStatus` equals `TAuthorizationStatus.Authorized`, and call it from `NotificationCenterPermissionRequestResult` if `AIsGranted` is `True`. Then you don't need `FIsNotificationAllowed`

Comment: @DaveNottage thank you, it works on my prototype.  But when I apply the same thing to my project, the app crashes when I wanted to show the notification. When I try to debug, it manages to run all the codes for the notification but it fails to show on my device and the app crashes... What would cause this to happen?

Comment: Sounds like a separate question, which should include code to reproduce the issue